# Wrapping image around objects in web app

Tags: asp.net, ajax, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm creating a web app in ASP.NET like this one:
http://www.zazzle.com/cr/design/pt-mug

I know how to do everything except wrapping an image around an object.
It would be a simple task to do if I would only have to stack an image on
top of the other, if they were flat, but if it is a round object, as this mug
is, it's kinda tricky.

My first guess was to create some sort of algorithm for GDI+ that would
simulate "wrapping" image around an object (actualy it wouldn't be an 3d object,
it would just be a screenshot of it).

I figured it would be to raw approach and it would result in very bad quality,
if I could ever make it work.

So, my second guess was to implement somekind of 3d renderer to whom I would
give an image map for some object, it would render me that image onto an object
and in real time return me rendered image. Is that posible?
Is there any other way? Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to try a commercial product, my company makes a raster processing SDK for .NET called [DotImage](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage). If you try it, take a look at `PolygonTransform`.  You supply a polygon as a list of points, and the class warps the image to fit inside the polygon.  If you need sample code for it, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into it and let you know :)

Comment: I took a look at your software, and I haven't found that PolygonTransform function. I've also looked at documentation at Atalsoft website and found nothing, so if you could direct me a little or send me some sample code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `PolygonTransform` is in `Atalasoft.Imaging.ImageProcessing.Transforms`.  It only supports convex polygons, but if you use a mug like on cafepress, that would work.  If you need concave polygons, you need to split up the image and use quadrilateral warps.  It would probably be easier if you contact us and give us a way to send you some code to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It might be some sort of OpenGL 3D rendering, but an image could easily be morphed in a purely 2D way for this effect.  Horizontally, it would need to be squished where it goes off the side of the cup.  Each column of pixels needs to be shifted vertically by varying amounts depending on which column - such that a horizontal line the image would become like a "U" shape.   With the right parameters, such a morph could mimic the proper 3D shape.   Lighting effects could be applied to, by brightening/darkening the image a bit in the right places.

Comment: OK, let's say that it would look nice
I can easily do that in photoshop :) 
but what kind of environment could I use besides GDI+ for this task?
GDI+ seems like a poor choice, cause it's not basically meant for
this kinda stuff.